# Selectively subscribing to an Observable based on a property in it

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, rxjs, observable

So basically I have an `Observable` which I want to subscribe to **ONLY** when a given property in it is set to true.

The case is that I store my search results in a `redux` state and I use it for both my quick search component and my full results component. The quick search auto-search with every keystroke (with a debounce) and a "quick results" are shown in a drop down. When you hit enter (or click the 'Search' button) you are redirected to the full results, when on the full results I do not want to update the full results if the user searches for something new in the quick search until he hits enter. So this is the state:

```js
state = {
    fullResults: boolean,
    results: SearchResult
}
```

I found the `takeWhile` method and took that to mean I would only subscribe while the condition was true, and thus tried this:

```js
search$.takeWhile((state) =>  state.fullResults).subscribe((state) => {
  this.search = state;
})
```

However, this still subscribes to every change. I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding the use of `takeWhile` or if I'm implementing it wrong. If this is the intended purpose, what have I done wrong? If not, is there another way to achieve this?

### Side note

I am using [`@angular-redux/store`](https://github.com/angular-redux/store) which has an awesome `@select` decorator which I noticed has a `comparable` parameter, could this perhaps be used to selectively subscribe as well?

Comment: Create a new observable which filters the underlying observable based on the desired property, then subscribe to that: `search$.filter(state => state.fullResults).subscribe(...`.

Comment: @torazaburo Would you mind answering with a more complete example of how you mean?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question "selectively subscribing based on a property in it" is problemmatic.The code can't know what is in a it without subscribing.

Comment: @georgeawg Since I'm not sure if this is a problem caused by my code (I'm merely asking if it possible and if so, how) I didn't think spending all that time on a more descriptive example was worthwhile. The case scenario alone should really be enough to answer the question but I added an example to make it easier. But sure, I get your point and will try to improve the example.

Answer (score 1):

> So basically I have an Observable which I want to subscribe to ONLY when a given property in it is set to true.

You've stated the problem in the wrong way. What you should say is:

> I have an Observable and I want to subscribe to only those elements of it for which a given property is true.

"Only those elements of" is implemented by the `filter` operator, which is applied to an observable, and results in a filtered observable. So to accomplish what you want, create a new observable which filters the underlying observable based on the desired property, then subscribe to that:

```
// Create a filtered observable.
const filteredSearch$ = search$.filter(state => state.fullResults);

// Subscribe to the filtered observable.
filteredSearch$.subscribe(state => this.search = state);
```

Comment: Thanks for adding an answer but this is literally the exact same text as in the comment. I was wanting to know where the new Observable comes into this scenario?

Comment: @Jan-ErikLysander Your comment: *I was wanting to know where the new Observable comes into this scenario?*, well it's impossible to tell you anything, since you have basically provided no code, so we cannot guess how your code looks like and tell you where exactly to place any pieces of code unless you provide a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve like already mentioned in a comment